# Ошибка 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 8: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, json

Прошу помочь как устранить ошибку. Ошибка выходит при попытке открыть json файл на jupyter notebook. Привожу код:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
with open('recipes.json') as f:
   recipes = json.load(f)
pprint(recipes)
```

Comment: Укажите кодировку при открытии файла. Возможно у вас файл в кодировке cp1251 (например), а у вас он судя по ошибке открывается в кодировке utf-8

Comment: В общем, в первую очередь покажите пример содержимого вашего файла. Также откройте файл каким-нибудь текстовым редактором, умеющим определять кодировку, и посмотрите какую кодировку он покажет. Дальше уже нужно будет в параметре encoding функции open указать эту кодировку.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать

```
with open("recipes.json", encoding="UTF-8"): ...
```

Comment: Ошибка "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte..." как бы намекает, что и так пытается открыть кодировкой utf-8

Answer (score 0):

имеем файл wheremi.json:

```json
{"status":"success","country":"USA Ñ","countryCode":"US","region":"VA","regionName":"Virgin","city":"Ashbern","zip":"","lat":39.0437,"lon":-77.4874,"timezone":"America/New_York","isp":"Google LLC","org":"Palo Alto Networks","as":"AS396982 Google LLC","query":"130.41.47.235"}
```

Пытаемся открыть:

```py
import json
    with open('wheremi.json') as f:
       recipes = json.load(f)
    print(recipes['country'])
```

На выходе:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 35: invalid continuation byte
```

Делаем:

```py
import json
from chardet.universaldetector import UniversalDetector

detector = UniversalDetector()

file = 'wheremi.json'

for line in open(file, 'rb'):
    detector.feed(line)
    if detector.done: break
    detector.close()


with open(file, encoding=detector.result['encoding']) as f:
    recipes = json.load(f)
print(recipes['country'])
```

Получаем:

```
USA Ñ
```

Comment: Ну это уже гадание на кофейной гуще. Так-то конечно, байт 0xd1 может оказаться и символом Ñ в кодировке latin-1, так и большой кириллической С в кодировке cp1251. Можно еще предположить, что раз файл называется recipes, то это какие-то рецепты, вероятно на русском, но это не точно.

Comment: Логично.
Это был просто пример.

Comment: @Delvin это был плохой пример неуниверсального решения.

Comment: благодарю всех, файл открылся)

Comment: @strawdog  ☝ так лучше?